# How to view the AWS lambda function created using AWS Toolkit for eclipse on AWS console

Tags: java, eclipse, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, toolkit

I have created AWS Lambda function using AWS Toolkit for Eclipse in Java. I am able to upload and invoke using eclipse. Now I want to add API endpoint. I don't see that lambda function created on the console where I can add API endpoints.

I do noticed that when i upload code it gets uploaded to S3 bucket. Do I have to create lambda function manually and upload code form s3 button to do it? If yes, I am getting invalid path when I add that in the box.

So my overall question is how should i add api endpoint to the lambda function created using AWS Toolkit for eclipse.

Here is the link that has the tutorial to use aws toolkit: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSToolkitEclipse/latest/ug/lambda-tutorial.html

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Different region selected in the console and in eclipse?

Comment: @zapl: Haha, you got me. Completely skipped this thing. Thanks